# how to initialize a pointer to a stack

Tags: c, pointers, struct, header

if we define a stack like this in a HEADER stack.h,

```
typedef struct stack *s;
stack empty();
```

and in the stack.c file we have this

```
struct stack {
    double size;
    double values[100];
};
```

how to write a function to return a created stack `stack empty();`, in .c the file .

Comment: You didn't define `stack`!

Comment: is it necessary to define it inside the header .h file ?

Comment: It is necessary to define it for this question to make sense. You said you've got `struct stack` and `s`, but you never defined `stack`

Comment: okey i'll try ,  thank you

Comment: Yes, for the second line of your header to make sense, the header needs to define the type `stack` before, not only the type `struct stack`. Or maybe the second line should read `struct stack` or `struct stack*`or `s`. Typedefing pointer types is by the way an idea of questionable wisdom.

Comment: You haven't define your stack yet. To check if the stack is empty you can do something like `if(top == -1)` Then `return 1` else `return 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your `stack empty()` function in your `stack.c` file like this:

```
struct stack *
empty() {
    struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof (struct stack));
    s->size = 0.0;
    return s;
}
```

But, you should move the entire definition of `struct stack` into the header file.